# Fastest way to find lines from a large file in another file

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, grep

I am using grep in a while loop to find lines from one file in another file and saving the output to a new file. My file is quite large (226 million lines) and the script is taking forever (12 days and counting). Do you have a suggestion to speed it up, perhaps there is a better way rather than grep?

(I also need the preceding line for the output, therefore grep -B 1.)

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  grep -B 1 $line K33.21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.dumps.fa >> 21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.diff.kmers.K33;
done <21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.diff.kmers
```

Update:

The input file with the lines to look for is 4.7 GB and 226 mio lines and looks like this:

```
AAAGAAAAAAAAAGCTAAAAT
ATCTCGACGCTCATCTCAGCA
GTTCGTCGGAGAGGAGAGAAC
GAGGACTATAAAATTGTCGCA
GGCTTCAATAATTTGTATAAC
GACATAGAATCACGAGTGACC
TGGTGAGTGACATCCTTGACA
ATGAAAACTGCCAGCAAACTC
AAAAAACTTACCTTAAAAAGT
TTAGTACACAATATCTCCCAA
```

The file to look in is 26 GB and 2 billion lines and looks like this:

```
>264638
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>1
AAAGAAAAAAAAAGCTAAAAT
>1
ATCTCGACGCTCATCTCAGCA
>1
GTTCGTCGGAGAGGAGAGAAC
>28
TCTTTTCAGGAGTAATAACAA
>13
AATCATTTTCCGCTGGAGAGA
>38
ATTCAATAAATAATAAATTAA
>2
GAGGACTATAAAATTGTCGCA
>1
GGCTTCAATAATTTGTATAAC
```

The expected output would be this:

```
>1
AAAGAAAAAAAAAGCTAAAAT
>1
ATCTCGACGCTCATCTCAGCA
>1
GTTCGTCGGAGAGGAGAGAAC
>2
GAGGACTATAAAATTGTCGCA
>1
GGCTTCAATAATTTGTATAAC
```

Comment: Yes of course, I have updated the question with more info on the files.

Comment: Faster might be to read a chunk (say, 1GB) and look for all lines in that. Then the next chunk, until done.

Comment: Do the sequences in the FASTA file span multiple lines? If so then you'll have to switch to a tool than can rebuild the complete sequences before searching for a match

Comment: @ElsaSverris : my suggestion - create a small `regex`, say, just for first 3-4 letters that might match your "needles", then pipe those down to another `awk` to `regex` scan for just letters 5-8, for instance (or do it in the same `awk` instance). After that, you've narrowed the search window significantly - and NOW you can do your `sort + grep` routine…..

don't pre-sort all the hay in the haystack for no reason

Comment: You could also dump the data into SQLite3 and let the indexes do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this `grep -f` command without shell loop and using a fixed string search:

```bash
grep -B1 -Ff 21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.diff.kmers \
 K33.21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.dumps.fa > 21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.diff.kmers.K33
```

Comment: This will load 226 million lines into `grep`'s memory as a lookup table, effectively much like Sundeep's `awk` solution (with similar memory caveats), but with a little more work scanning for the start of the key string in each letter of the target line. I suspect adding a `-x` would speed it up if it can work, but I've also seen`grep` *really* lose efficiency with large search files on some systems. YMMV.

Comment: fwiw, a 200MB `*.kmers` file (9 million lines @ 21 chars per line) `grep -f` requires ~1,200 MB of memory (per `/usr/bin/time -v`) for a factor of ~6; for OP's 4.7GB file this equates to ~28GB of RAM

Comment: Thank you so much for that suggestion, it solved my problem, and only took 155 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few tools (e.g. `ripgrep`) and options (`-f`, `-F`, and `-x`) to speed up your basic approach. But all of them are basically the same slow approach as you are using now, "only" sped up by a huge but still *constant* factor. For your problem and input sizes, I'd recommend to change the approach altogether. There are many different ways to tackle your problem. First, lets define some variables to estimate the speedup of those approaches:

## Problem

A 26 GB **haystack** file with **h** = 1 million entries (description, sequence) = 2 billion lines, e.g.

```
>28
TCTTTTCAGGAGTAATAACAA
>13
AATCATTTTCCGCTGGAGAGA
>38
ATTCAATAAATAATAAATTAA
...
```

A 4.7 GB **needles** file with **n** = 226 million lines, each of length **m** = 21, e.g.

```
GACATAGAATCACGAGTGACC
TGGTGAGTGACATCCTTGACA
ATGAAAACTGCCAGCAAACTC
...
```

For all needles, we want to extract the corresponding entries in the haystack (if they exist).

## Solutions

We assume n < h and a constant m. Therefore O(n+h) = O(h), O(m)=O(1) and so on.
Our goal is to minimize the number of times we have to iterate the the biggest file (= the haystack).

### Naive – O(h·n) time

Currently, you are using the naive approach. For each needle, the entire haystack is searched once.

### Put needles into data structure; search haystack once – O(h) time

Store all needles in a data structure which has a fast `contains()` operation.
Then iterate the haystack and call `needles.contains(haystackEntry)` for each entry, to decide whether it is something you are searching for.

Currently, your "data structure" is a list, which takes O(1) time to "build" (because it is already in that form) , but O(n) time to query *once*!
Below data structures take O(n) time to populate and O(1) time to query once, resulting in O(n + h·1) = O(h) time in total.

- [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)s (= prefix trees) can be expressed as a regexes, so you can stick with `grep`. E.g. the needles `ABC`, `ABX`, and `XBC` can be stored in the Trie regex `^(AB(C|X)|XBC)`. But converting the list of needles to such a Trie regex is a bit complicated in bash.
- Hash maps are available in `awk`, see [sundeep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74983931/6770384). But putting 4.7 GB of raw data in such a structure in memory is probably not very efficient if even possible (depends on your available memory. The hash map needs to be many times bigger than the raw data).

Either way, data structures and bash don't mix very well. And even if we switched to a better language, we would have to re-build or store/load the structure each time the program runs. Therefore it is easier and nearly as efficient to ...

### Sort everything; search haystack once – O( h·log(h) + h ) time

First sort the haystack *and* the needles, then iterate the haystack only once.

Take the first needle and search the haystack from the beginning. When reaching a haystack entry that would have to be sorted behind the the current needle, take the next needle and continue the search from your current location.

This can be done easily in bash. Here we use GNU coreutils to make processing a bit easier, faster, and safer:

```
export LC_ALL=C  # speeds up sorting
mem=66%    # Max. memory to be used while sorting. More is better.
sep=$'\f'  # A character not appearing in your data.

paste -d"$sep" - -  < haystack > haystack2

sort -S"$mem" -o needles2 needles
sort -S"$mem" -t"$sep" -k2,2 -o haystack2 haystack2

# --nocheck-order is not needed, but speeds up the process
join -t"$sep" -22 -o2.1,2.2 --nocheck-order needles2 haystack2 |
tr "$sep" \\n
```

This changes the order of the output. If you need the output in the original order, use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (= decorate-sort-undecorate): Before sorting the needles/haystack, store their line numbers. Drag those along through the entire process. At the end, sort the found entries by those line numbers. Finally, remove the line numbers and print the result.

```
export LC_ALL=C  # speeds up sorting
mem=66%    # Max. memory to be used while sorting. More is better.
sep=$'\f'  # A character not appearing in your data.

nl -ba -d '' -s"$sep" needles > needles2
paste -d"$sep" - -  < haystack | nl -ba -d '' -s"$sep" > haystack2

sort -t"$sep" -k2,2 -S"$mem" -o needles2 needles2
sort -t"$sep" -k3,3 -S"$mem" -o haystack2 haystack2

# --nocheck-order is not needed, but speeds up the process
join -t"$sep" -12 -23 -o1.1,2.1,2.2,2.3 --nocheck-order needles2 haystack2 > result
sort -t"$sep" -k1,2n -S"$mem" -o result result
cut -d"$sep" -f3- result | tr "$sep" \\n
```

Answer (score 3):

If preserving the original order is not required, using GNU `uniq` and GNU `sed`:

```
{ cat 21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.diff.kmers
  sed -n 'x;n;G;s/\n//p' K33.21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.dumps.fa
} | LC_ALL=C sort | uniq -w21 -D |
sed -n 's/\(.*\)>\(.*\)/>\2\n\1/p' > 21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.diff.kmers.K33
```

Comment: Nice idea! Took me a while to understand, so here are hints for the reader: `sed -n 'x;n;G;s/\n//p'` processes pairs of lines from the big file. For each pair, the lines are swapped and written in a single line, e.g. the result for OPs example is  `AAAAA…AA>264638`, `AAAGA…AAT>1`, …. After that we basically do a `join`, but under the assumption that each sequence (e.g. `ATCT...`) is exactly 21 characters long and unique within each file. Therefore, we use `uniq -D` (print duplicate lines) instead of `join`. Not sure if `uniq` is faster, but it certainly is easier to write.

Comment: The original order can be restored by decorating/sorting+undecorating the lines with/by their original line numbers before/after the actual processing. See [end of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74985439/6770384) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `awk`. Not sure if it will be faster than `grep` or `ripgrep`, but it is possible due to hash-based lookup. This assumes your RAM is big enough to load the first file (4.7 GB and 226 mio lines).

```bash
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $0 in a{print p; print} {p=$0}' f1 f2
>1
AAAGAAAAAAAAAGCTAAAAT
>1
ATCTCGACGCTCATCTCAGCA
>1
GTTCGTCGGAGAGGAGAGAAC
>2
GAGGACTATAAAATTGTCGCA
>1
GGCTTCAATAATTTGTATAAC
```

`mawk` is usually the fastest option, but I have come across examples where `gawk` is faster, especially for arrays like in this command. If you can install [frawk](https://github.com/ezrosent/frawk), that can give you even faster results. Command needs to be slightly modified:

```bash
frawk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $0 in a{print p; print $0} {p=$0}' f1 f2
```

Comment: fwiw, in my environment (`GNU awk v 5.1.1`) I'm seeing `a[]` array memory usage running ~8.5 times the size of the input file; for a 200MB file (900K lines; 21 chars per line like OP's file) the `a[]` array requires ~1,700 MB of RAM, so ~8.5 times the size of the input file; for OP's input file of 4.7GB this means the `a[]` array will require ~40GB of RAM

Comment: If you have that kind of resources available, this is probably the fastest AND simplest solution - reads each file only once, doesn't require sorting, etc - and I have worked places where this was just what you do, so the machines could handle it. Generally, though, I've had to find more mechanical solutions.

Comment: typo re: my previous comment ... the 200MB file is *9 million* lines @ 21 chars (+\n) per line

Answer (score 1):

Any time I deal with files this big, I almost always end up sorting them. Sorts are slow, but take a lot less time that your `while read` loop that is scanning 2 billion lines 226 million times.

```
sort 4GB>4gb.srt
```

and

```
sed '/>/{N;s/\n/ /}' 26GB |sort -t' ' -k2 >25gb.srt
```

which will produce a file like this:

```
>264638 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>1 AAAGAAAAAAAAAGCTAAAAT
>13 AATCATTTTCCGCTGGAGAGA
>1 ATCTCGACGCTCATCTCAGCA
>38 ATTCAATAAATAATAAATTAA
>2 GAGGACTATAAAATTGTCGCA
>1 GGCTTCAATAATTTGTATAAC
>1 GTTCGTCGGAGAGGAGAGAAC
>28 TCTTTTCAGGAGTAATAACAA
```

Now you only have to read through each file once.

```
$ cat tst
awk 'BEGIN{ getline key < "4gb.srt"; }
 $2  < key { next; }
 $2  > key { while ($2 > key){ getline key < "4gb.srt"; } }
 $2 == key {  $0=gensub(/ /,"\n",1); print }' 25gb.srt

$ ./tst
>1
AAAGAAAAAAAAAGCTAAAAT
>1
ATCTCGACGCTCATCTCAGCA
>2
GAGGACTATAAAATTGTCGCA
>1
GGCTTCAATAATTTGTATAAC
>1
GTTCGTCGGAGAGGAGAGAAC
```

The ordering is different from yours, but otherwise does that work?

(Try some tests with smaller files first...)

## addendum

Please c.f. [Socowi's better implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74985439/8656552), but I was asked to explain the `awk`, so -

First, see above where I parsed the larger "haystraw" file to single lines sorted on the key field, which will be `$2` in `awk`, and the smaller "needles" file in the same order. Making a few (not necessarily safe) assumptions, I ran through both once.

```
BEGIN{ getline key < "4gb.srt"; }
```

This just initializes the first "needle" into a variable called `key` by reading from the appropriate file.

Then as `awk` reads each line of the "haystraw" file, it automatically parses it into the fields - since we stacked them, the first field is the previous line of the original haystack, and the second field is the value to check, so we do our comparisons between `key` and `$2`.

```
 $2  < key { next; } # skip ahead to next key/needle
```

If the current straw is less than the needle, throw it away and grab the next one.

```
 $2  > key { while ($2 > key){ getline key < "4gb.srt"; } }
```

If the current straw is *greater* than the needle, then the needle wasn't in the file. The next one might not be either, so we grab needles in sequential order and compare then until they catch up.

There's actually a potential bug here - it's not confirming that something was read and could hang in an endless loop when the needles run out. This section *should* have been something like -

```
 $2  > key { while ( ($2 > key) { if( 0 == getline key < "4gb.srt" ) key = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"; } }
```

Finally,

```
 $2 == key {  $0=gensub(/ /,"\n",1); print }' 25gb.srt
```

If they match, reinsert the newline between the previous record and the matching line, and print them both.

There really should also have been an `END{ close("4gb.srt") }` as well.

Comment: One more thing -- do NOT include the sorting in your code. Do that in advance, *ONCE*, so that if anything goes wrong you don't have to wait for it to do it again. Sorting that many records isn't going to be super fast, so fire it off and go work on your test scripts with small samples while it runs. You can delete the files when you no longer  need them, but you don't want to have to go through that sort over and over if ANYTHING goes wrong.

Comment: any chance you can explain the tst code?

Comment: @Supertech Looks like the `awk` script in `./tst` is a (slow) re-implementation of the `join` command. I explained this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74985439/6770384). Quote: *Take the first needle and search the haystack from the beginning. When reaching a haystack entry that would have to be sorted behind the the current needle, take the next needle and continue the search from the current location.*

Comment: Yep. Less familiar with `join` so I use the multitool pliers instead of the appropriately sized wrench. Gonna go sort my toolbox and do some shopping. :)

Answer (score 0):

grep can search for many patterns (given in a separate file) simultaneously, so reading K33.21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.dumps.fa will only be done once.
Something like the following might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep --f 21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.diff.kmers -B 1 K33.21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.dumps.fa >> 21mercounts.bf.trimmedreads.diff.kmers.K33;
```

However, it probably requires lots of RAM